# Как сделать , чтобы без введенной капчи бот не работал?

Tags: python, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def test_captcha(message):
    captcha_manager.send_new_captcha(bot, message.chat, message.from_user)



# Callback query handler
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def on_callback(callback):
    captcha_manager.update_captcha(bot, callback)


# Handler for correct solved CAPTCHAs
@captcha_manager.on_captcha_correct
def on_correct(captcha):
    verno=bot.send_message(captcha.chat.id, "✅ : Congrats! You solved the CAPTCHA! /menu")
    captcha_manager.delete_captcha(bot, captcha)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(verno, start)


# Handler for wrong solved CAPTCHAs
@captcha_manager.on_captcha_not_correct
def on_not_correct(captcha):
    neverno=bot.send_message(captcha.chat.id, f"❌ : You failed solving the CAPTCHA!")
    captcha_manager.delete_captcha(bot, captcha)



# Handler for timed out CAPTCHAS
@captcha_manager.on_captcha_timeout
def on_timeout(captcha):
    vremya=bot.send_message(captcha.chat.id, f"❌ : You did not solve the CAPTCHA!")
    captcha_manager.delete_captcha(bot, captcha)



#@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def start(message):

    mess = f'<i>Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, для заказа выбери город</i>'
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1) #ВЫБОР РЕГИОНА
    moscow = types.KeyboardButton('Москва')
```

Если написать без решенной капчи бот реагирует все равно, и получается , что от капчи смысла нет

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это уже 5й дубликат вопроса от этого автора за 24 часа

Comment: Первый вопрос с таким содержанием, реально не понимаю, как сделать, а получается тут токсичное комьюнити

Comment: Да да... Один Вы Д'Артаньян

Comment: Так ,дружище ,вопрос полезный, может кто то из малого и среднего бизнеса захочет создать бота, и чтобы не было навождения от ботов ,которых запустили конкуренты, например, нужна будет капча, а на просторах интернета нет информации, как создать капчу не для чат-бота